# Key Value Coding: BOOL property evaluated as NSNumber of type "i", not "c"

Tags: cocoa

When using `NSObject valueForKey:` for a property of type BOOL (Example code from someone else [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/60455-bug-sdk.html)), the NSNumber returned isn't `@encode(BOOL) = "c"` -- it's "i". Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BOOL` isn't a fundamental type, it's a typedef for `signed char`. As such, at runtime it's impossible to tell if a property is a boolean or just an integral value. Therefore we can be certain that `-valueForKey:` is not using `+numberWithBool:` to wrap the value. So the question is, why isn't it using `+numberWithChar:`? Probably for simplicity sake. It would not surprise me if all signed integral values <= `sizeof(int)` are wrapped using `+numberWithInt:`. The real question is, why does it matter? If you ask the resulting `NSNumber` object for `-boolValue` you'll get the correct response.

Comment: The question is mostly just pedagogical, but I found it when testing `@encode(BOOL)` vs the `NSNumber objCType` which doesn't work as expected. I wonder what the result would be when using C99 bool? According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html), there is a special type devoted to this form of bool.

Comment: @Stephen: Good question. `NSNumber` doesn't appear to have any initializers for C99 `bool` though, so I would expect it to use one of the integral types that are >= `sizeof(bool)`, such as `int`.

Answer (score -1):

This was the code from the linked website:

```
MyClass *c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
c.aaa = YES;

NSNumber *n = [c valueForKey:@"aaa"];

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCString:[n objCType] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"ObjC type - %@", s); // Prints 'i' instead of 'c'
```

It seems to be that you are asking for `n`'s `objCType` when using `[n objCType];`
Since `n` is an `NSNumber`, it would follow that `i` is the result and not `c`.

Comment: `NSNumber`'s don't necessarily have the type `i`.